# Spring Integration Tcp connection single-use VS setSoKeepAlive

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I was using

```
TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
```

for TcpOutboundGateway, normally TcpOutboundGateway is working req/reply order but in my case I extend TcpOutboundGateway to receive arbitrary messages with MessageChannel. This is why ı thought that i should use

```
cf.setLeaveOpen(true)
```

to keep connection open.

Although i started to use that option, after long time when i called tcp server again i have received
Exception like

> org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response

but i did not understand why i am taking this error because i set "true" to keep connection open in my connection factory.

THEN

I did some google and it was supposed to use CachingClientConnectionFactory, I understand that it is by default single-use=true and not supposed to change it false, but then i assume that connection will be open and close in my each request response transaction so is it obstacle to receive arbitrary data from server without any request from client ?

OR

How should i keep open connection between client and server ? should i use

> cf.setSoKeepAlive(true) ?

to keep connection open ?
Are

> cf.setSoKeepAlive(true) and cf.setLeaveOpen(true)

same with each other ?

> EDIT

Also when i use cf.setSoKeepAlive(true), after 1 hour i got same exception too.

Full code :

```
private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
    String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
    Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");

    boolean hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel = message.getHeaders().containsKey("irregularMessageChannelName");


    Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
    String flowRegisterKey;

    if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
        flowRegisterKey = host + port + ".extended";
    } else {
        flowRegisterKey = host + port;
    }

    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);

    CachingClientConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingClientConnectionFactory(cf, 20);
    ccf.setSoKeepAlive(true);

    ByteArrayCrLfSerializer byteArrayCrLfSerializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
    byteArrayCrLfSerializer.setMaxMessageSize(1048576);

    ccf.setSerializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);
    ccf.setDeserializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);

    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway;
    if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
        String unsolicitedMessageChannelName = (String) message.getHeaders().get("irregularMessageChannelName");
        DirectChannel directChannel = getBeanFactory().getBean(unsolicitedMessageChannelName, DirectChannel.class);
        tcpOutboundGateway = new ExtendedTcpOutboundGateway(directChannel);
    } else {
        tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    }
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(20000);

    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(ccf);

    IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(tcpOutboundGateway);

    IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
        this.flowContext.registration(flow)
            .addBean(ccf)
            .id(flowRegisterKey + ".flow")
            .register();

    MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();

    this.subFlows.put(flowRegisterKey, inputChannel);
    return inputChannel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the `CachingClientConnectionFactory`? It is not needed when you keep the connection open; it is intended to be used when you want to maintain multiple open connections.

> Timed out waiting for response

Means the socket was open just fine (from the client's perspective) when you sent the request; we just didn't get a reply. This could mean that some network component (router) silently closed the socket due to inactivity. Keep-alives should help with that but it depends on your operating system and how often the TCP stack is configured to send keep alives.

Comment: I was using only `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` but then i googled similar issues and found that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918267/how-to-implement-a-keep-alive-connection-on-a-tcp-connection-using-spring-integr) this is why ı thought that i should use it. Do you think that i should continue with  `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` ? then my issue still remains same. How should i keep connection open ? Should i use one of them `factory.setSoTimeout()`or `gateway.setRequestTimeout()` or `gateway.setRemoteTimeout()` .

Comment: Also in this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192422/which-timeouts-to-set-on-socket-created-with-spring-integration) you proposed to setSoTimeOut as 0. Is its default value is inifinite ? Is there another way to handle connection close event then open it again with using handler ?

Comment: Also in log i found this `cause=java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`

Comment: I think the 3 timeouts are adequately described in the answer linked from your second comment. `Socket closed` perhaps the server closes the socket if it receives no data for a certain time, or it could be some network component (router, firewall etc). It's hard for me to tell.

Comment: hmm then i will check operating system level parameter as you mentioned, i will provide my results but on the other hand does spring integration have capability to handle connection closed or socket closed and open it again ?

Comment: You an add a [retry advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the gateway.

Comment: hi thank you for help,  I found that TcpOutboundGateway has public void setAdviceChain(List<Advice> adviceChain) method so should i add it with coding or as a bean definition. ın this link it was mentioned with xml definition [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746778/spring-integration-retry-to-establish-connection-on-exception-scenarios), in github examples do you have example section for it ?

Comment: Add the retry advice as a `@Bean` (you don't need a new one for each gateway) and yes, use that setter to add it to the gatdwaye

Comment: Thank you Gary, i have tried and it is reconnected successfully.